# Join / split search words in elasticsearch (using tire)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire, fuzzy-search

I have the following analyzer (a slight tweak to the way snowball would be setup):

```
  string_analyzer: {
    filter: [ "standard", "stop", "snowball" ],
    tokenizer: "lowercase"
  }
```

Here is the field it is applied to:

```
  indexes :title, type: 'string', analyzer: 'string_analyzer'

  query do
    match ['title'], search_terms, fuzziness: 0.5, max_expansions: 10, operator: 'and'
  end
```

I have a record in my index with title `foo bar`.

If I search for `foo bar` it appears in the results.

However, if I search for `foobar` it doesn't.

Can someone explain why and if possible how I could get it to?

Can someone explain how I could get the reverse of this to work as well so that if I had a record with title `foobar` a user could search for `foo bar` and see it as a result?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only search for tokens that are in your index. So let's look at what you are indexing.
You're currently using the `lowercase` tokenizer (which tokenizes a string on non-letter characters and lowercases them) then applying the `standard` filter (redundant, because you are not using the `standard` tokenizer), the `stop` and `snowball` filters.

If we create that analyzer:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "analyzer" : {
            "string_analyzer" : {
               "filter" : [
                  "standard",
                  "stop",
                  "snowball"
               ],
               "tokenizer" : "lowercase"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

and use the `analyze` API to test it out:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/_analyze?pretty=1&text=foo+bar&analyzer=string_analyzer'
```

you'll see that `"foo bar"` produces the terms `["foo","bar"]` and `"foobar"` produces the term `["foobar"]`.  So indexing `"foo bar"` and searching for `"foobar"` currently cannot work.

If you want to be able to search "inside" words, then you need to break words up into smaller tokens.  To do this, we use the `ngram` analyzer.

So delete the test index:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/?pretty=1'
```

and specify a new analyzer:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "filter" : {
            "ngrams" : {
               "max_gram" : 5,
               "min_gram" : 1,
               "type" : "ngram"
            }
         },
         "analyzer" : {
            "ngrams" : {
               "filter" : [
                  "standard",
                  "lowercase",
                  "ngrams"
               ],
               "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

Now, if we test the analyzer, we get:

```
"foo bar" => [f,o,o,fo,oo,foo,b,a,r,ba,ar,bar]
"foobar"  => [f,o,o,b,a,r,fo,oo,ob,ba,ar,foo,oob,oba,bar,foob,ooba,obar,fooba,oobar]
```

So if we index `"foo bar"` and we search for `"foobar"` using the `match` query, then the query becomes a query looking for any of those tokens, some of which exist in the index.

Unfortunately, it'll also overlap with `"wear the fox hat"` (`f`,`o`,`a`). While `foobar` will appear higher up the list of results because it has more tokens in common, you will still get apparently unrelated results.

This can be controlled by using the `minimum_should_match` parameter, eg:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "my_field" : {
            "minimum_should_match" : "60%",
            "query" : "foobar"
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

The exact value for `minimim_should_match` depends upon your data - experiment with it.

Comment: Thanks DrTech. Is there anything to gain by adding snowball as a filter or is there no point since the start of the words would be matched against the search term anyway using the ngrams filter anyway?

Comment: And is there a particular reason for removing the stop filter or is it just that some of the words the stop filter could remove might be chunks of the ngrams filter?

Comment: Correct, nothing to gain by using the snowball filter, for the reasons you state, and yes, stop words could interfere with ngrams.  I wouldn't be afraid of stopwords. Have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/a/14661309/819598

Comment: Thanks DrTech. I've got a small issue. I can now search using `foo bar` and it returns those that contain `foo bar` and `foobar` but I can't seem to do the reverse - search using `foobar` and return both results. I can see that that may be caused by the fact that the record with `foo bar` never has an index item that matches `foobar`. Is there a way? I think I may be trying to cover to many search possibilities.

Comment: Have you mapped `my_field` to use the `ngrams` analyzer? Are you querying exactly as above? If so, then `minimum_should_match` would need to be set to 30% or lower in order for a query of `foobar` to match `foo` or `bar` as well.

Comment: DrTech, rather than dropping down the `minimum_should_match` is there a way to use a shingle token filter?